# Is there a clean way of disabiling RX control from USBCore in leonardo?

Tags: c++, arduino

At the moment I'm trying to use the sparkfun promicro to control the RX pin at will using this sketch https://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/338 .

However I have run into a problem where despite having control over the RX and TX led, it is being interfered by the USBCore.cpp in arduino. I am wondering if there is a clean way to disable control by USBCore over RX and TX pins, while still leaving the USB serial alone, so that I can control these pins directly, even while receiving and sending serial data.

```
/* Pro Micro Test Code
   by: Nathan Seidle
   modified by: Jim Lindblom
   SparkFun Electronics
   date: January 20, 2012
   license: Public Domain - please use this code however you'd like.
   It's provided as a learning tool.

   This code is provided to show how to control the SparkFun
   ProMicro's TX and RX LEDs within a sketch. It also serves
   to explain the difference between Serial.print() and
   Serial1.print().
*/
int RXLED = 17;  // The RX LED has a defined Arduino pin
// The TX LED was not so lucky, we'll need to use pre-defined
// macros (TXLED1, TXLED0) to control that.

void setup()
{
 pinMode(RXLED, OUTPUT);  // Set RX LED as an output
 // TX LED is set as an output behind the scenes

 Serial.begin(9600); //This pipes to the serial monitor
 Serial1.begin(9600); //This is the UART, pipes to sensors attached to board
}

void loop()
{
 Serial.println("Hello world");  // Print "Hello World" to the Serial Monitor
 Serial1.println("Hello!");  // Print "Hello!" over hardware UART

 digitalWrite(RXLED, HIGH);   // set the LED on
 TXLED1; //TX LED is not tied to a normally controlled pin
 delay(1000);              // wait for a second
 digitalWrite(RXLED, LOW);    // set the LED off
 TXLED0;
 delay(1000);              // wait for a second
}
```

If there is no way to tackle this cleanly without modifying the arduino enviroment, then I'll shall modify USBCore.cpp . However its probbly bad practice to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its possible in your scenario, you could use pin 17 as an INPUT, hopefully freeing up another pin which you can then use as an OUTPUT.

To do this, just use pinMode() to set pin 17 to an INPUT.

That effectively disables the RXLED functionality.  When USBCore write a high to that pin, it merely turns on the pullup resistor.  As long as the device driving the input can sink enough current even when the pullup is on, this will have no effect.  And so there is no need to modify USBCore.

Edit: The LED lights up when pin 17 is low, which means the source of the signal needs to sink current.  That can be avoided if its an issue by severing the PCB track next to the LED, or by desoldering the LED or resistor.